# PHP Sum Total of Elements from Checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

What would be the best way to output the values of the check boxes which are checked, but I want to get a total.  I have tried to use sum() to total the values selected but I just keep getting double 0 0.

My checkbox.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['shipping'])) {

 ?>
 <div class="container"> <?php
 //Loop through shipping array to fetch individual shipping so that we     can use them
 echo "<h2> Your Shipping Costs are: </h2>";
 foreach($_POST['shipping'] as $shipping) {
 //Print all the shipping
  echo $shipping;
  }

  }
  else{
  echo "<b>Please Select at least One Option.</b>";
  }
  ?></div><?php }
   ?>
```

then my html

```
 <div class="container">
    <form action="checkbox.php" method="post">

       <label class="head">Select Your Timezone or Other Shipping  Options:</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$190.00"> <label>Freight to Eastern USA</label><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$245.00"><label>Freight to Western USA</label><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$75.00"><label>Residential Devivery</label><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$100.00"><label>Liftgate Service</label><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$0.00"><label>Will Call</label><br/><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Add to Shopping Cart"/>

    </form>
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're not getting results because of the dollar signs in `value="$xxx"`. You'll need to either remove them, or explode and seperate. If you're going to get rid of the dollar signs, you can always concatenate after `echo "$". $shipping;`

Comment: However, I can't see why shipping should be any more than one option. You're best to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP Sum Total of Elements from Checkboxes

You need to remove the dollar sign (`$`) in order to `sum` the values.
Use something like:

```
foreach($_POST['shipping'] as $shipping) {
    $shipping = str_replace("\$", "", $shipping);
    $sum +=  $shipping;
  }
    echo "\$".$sum;
```

Comment: That worked great. I tried to use $sum += $shipping then echo $sum  before but it would not work. My problem was I never knew I had to remove the $ sign. Thank you Pedro

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign must be removed prior to adding the values:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['shipping'])) {
        echo('<div class="container">');
        //Loop through shipping array to fetch individual shipping so that we can use them
        echo "<h2> Your Shipping Costs are: </h2>";
        $shipping_subtotal = 0.0;
        foreach($_POST['shipping'] as $shipping){
            //Sum all the shipping
            $shipping_subtotal += floatval(substr($shipping,1,strlen($shipping)-1));
        }
        echo('<div>The shipping subtotal is $'.number_format($shipping_subtotal,2,'.',',').'</div>');
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Please Select at least One Option.</b>";
    }
    echo('</div>');
}
?>
```

This would work with your HTML as-is, however, I would like to recommend making some changes to your HTML. The `value` attribute of an `<input type="checkbox" />` is not shown to the user. Therefore it would be better to exclude the dollar signs altogether and leave just double values instead. Since the `value` attribute is not displayed, the dollar amount still needs to be displayed for the customer. Also, it would probably be more appropriate to use `<input type="radio" />` to prevent the user from selecting multiple shipping options, unless of course you want the customer to request multiple shipping options for their order. I'll leave that up to you  Here is the recommended, simplified code:

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['shipping'])) {
        echo('<div class="container">');
        //Loop through shipping array to fetch individual shipping so that we can use them
        echo "<h2> Your Shipping Costs are: </h2>";
        /*
        //only if input type="checkbox"
        $shipping_subtotal = 0.0;
        foreach($_POST['shipping'] as $shipping){
            //Sum all the shipping
                        substr();
            $shipping_subtotal += $shipping;
        }
        */
        $shipping_subtotal = (double) $_POST['shipping'];
        echo('<div>The shipping subtotal is $'.number_format($shipping_subtotal,2,'.',',').'</div>');
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Please Select at least One Option.</b>";
    }
    echo('</div>');
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="tmp.php" method="post">
        <label class="head">Shipping Options:</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="190.00"> <label>$190 Freight to Eastern USA</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="245.00"><label>$245 Freight to Western USA</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="75.00"><label>$75 Residential Devivery</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="100.00"><label>$100 Liftgate Service</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="0.00"><label>Will Call</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Add to Shopping Cart"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer it works great but I do want to allow the customer to make several choices. Thank you for the help